# Run a javascript function when an audio is played

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run a javascript function whenever an audio file is played using HTML5. How can I do it?

If possible, for videos too!

Comment: Where have you looked? Where are you running into trouble? As it reads now (and this may well not be the case) it *looks* like you've decided to have the SO community do all your research for you, which tends not to go over well.

Comment: I'm sorry? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @ Rehan: Surely the question is clear? *What research have you done?* Where are you running into trouble? For instance, the *slightest* most glancing bit of research would have taken you to the HTML5 spec, which lists the very event BenM points you at below. But it would appear that rather than do the *slightest* bit of work yourself, you've decided to just let other people do it for you. That's not what SO is for. SO is for helping people who are stuck on a problem. It's not a replacement for doing the basic work yourself.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for that! @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML5 `audio` element includes the `onplay` event. You can bind into it as follows:

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('audio_element');
myAudio.onplay = function(e) {
    // Your JavaScript function here...
};
```

The `video` element also includes this event.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, you might want to accept the answer ;)